# Calling a soap method which is a message contract from soap.js

Tags: javascript, wcf, soap

I have a soap service that uses message contracts. 
The rules for message contracts is that the request and response massage needs to be an object. I need to use message contract because I need full control over the request/response body.

So you can not define a message contract endpoint like this: 
public Object getData(int id)... (as far as I understand)

So I made an object to parse in the incoming value

```
[MessageContract]
public class Value
{
  [MessageBodyMember]
  public string id {get; set;}
}
```

and the endpoint public Object getData(Value id)

This works now with the soap client only like this:
client.getData({"id":"123"}, (error,response) => {...})

But I need to be able to call the soap service from soap.js like this. 
client.getData({id}, (error,response) => {...}), but if I do the incomming value is not recognised.

Changing the implementation of the code that uses the soap client is not optional for me because it comes from a private npm package that I would rather not change, and might be updated at any time, but I control the soap service.

How can I implement the soap service that will recognise what ever value is sent over (using Message contract)?

Comment: I think I might have been to quick of my feet. It seems like soap.js is reading my wsdl incorrectly. But it would be nice to know how other people are doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed. Error in wsdl that soap.js reads.